# Python Criar JSON a partir de um XML

Tags: python, json, xml

Segue o xml abaixo.

```
    <tree>            
        <item>
           <name>OperatingSystem</name>
           <parent>0</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>RED</HighAlertValue>               
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Filesystems</name>
           <parent>1</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>/dev</name>
           <parent>2</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Name</name>
           <parent>3</parent>
           <ActualValue>GRAY</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>EXPERT</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Freespace</name>
           <parent>3</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Percentage_Used</name>
           <parent>3</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>/dev/shm</name>
           <parent>2</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Name</name>
           <parent>7</parent>
           <ActualValue>GRAY</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>EXPERT</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Freespace</name>
           <parent>7</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>               
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Percentage_Used</name>
           <parent>7</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>/run</name>
           <parent>2</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Name</name>
           <parent>11</parent>
           <ActualValue>GRAY</ActualValue>
           <VisibleLevel>EXPERT</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Freespace</name>
           <parent>11</parent>
           <ActualValue>GREEN</ActualValue>               
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
        <item>
           <name>Percentage_Used</name>
           <parent>11</parent>
           <VisibleLevel>OPERATOR</VisibleLevel>
           <HighAlertValue>GREEN</HighAlertValue>
        </item>
    </tree>
```

Preciso converte-lo em JSON da seguinte forma:

```
[    {
      "name":"OperatingSystem",
      "parent":0,
      "ActualValue":"GREEN",      
      "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
      "HighAlertValue":"RED",      
      "Filesystems":[
         {
            "name":"Filesystems",
            "parent":1,
            "ActualValue":"GREEN",            
            "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
            "HighAlertValue":"GREEN",
            "/dev":[
               {
                  "name":"/dev",
                  "parent":2,
                  "ActualValue":"GREEN",                  
                  "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
                  "HighAlertValue":"GREEN",
                  "data":[
                     {
                        "name":"Name",
                        "parent":3,
                        "ActualValue":"GRAY",
                        "VisibleLevel":"EXPERT",
                        "HighAlertValue":"GREEN",
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Freespace",
                        "parent":3,
                        "ActualValue":"GREEN",
                        "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
                        "HighAlertValue":"GREEN",
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Percentage_Used",
                        "parent":3,
                        "ActualValue":"GREEN",
                        "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
                        "HighAlertValue":"GREEN",
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "/dev/shm":[
               {
                  "name":"/dev/shm",
                  "parent":2,
                  "ActualValue":"GREEN",                  
                  "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
                  "HighAlertValue":"GREEN",                  
                  "data":[
                     {
                        "name":"Name",
                        "parent":7,
                        "ActualValue":"GRAY",
                        "VisibleLevel":"EXPERT",
                        "HighAlertValue":"GREEN"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Freespace",
                        "parent":7,
                        "ActualValue":"GREEN",
                        "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
                        "HighAlertValue":"GREEN"
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"Percentage_Used",
                        "parent":7,
                        "ActualValue":"GREEN",
                        "VisibleLevel":"OPERATOR",
                        "HighAlertValue":"GREEN"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "/run":[
               {
                  "name": "/run",
                  "parent": 2,
                  "ActualValue": "GREEN",                  
                  "VisibleLevel": "OPERATOR",
                  "HighAlertValue": "GREEN"
                  "data":[
                     {
                        "name": "Name",
                        "parent": 11,
                        "ActualValue": "GRAY",
                        "VisibleLevel": "EXPERT",
                        "HighAlertValue": "GREEN"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "Freespace",
                        "parent": 11,
                        "ActualValue": "GREEN",
                        "VisibleLevel": "OPERATOR",
                        "HighAlertValue": "GREEN",
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "Percentage_Used",
                        "parent": 11,
                        "ActualValue": "GREEN",
                        "VisibleLevel": "OPERATOR",
                        "HighAlertValue": "GREEN",
                      }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]    } ]
```

E preciso que seja feito em python. O problema aqui é qual lógica devo usar para gerar um arquivo json a partir desse xml.

Answer (score -2):

O ideal nestes casos é usar uma função recursiva porque pode haver sub-pastas. Da maneira que está temos três níveis: o sistema operativo, os filesystems e os dados desses filesystems.

Começamos por adicionar os sistemas operativos a uma lista e para cada item vamos buscar os descendentes.

Para ler XML é preciso instalar os pacotes beautifulsoup4 e lxml.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

with open('file.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read() 

bs_data = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml') 

tree = bs_data.find('tree')
items = tree.findChildren("item" , recursive=False)
count = 0

def get_children(parent):
    children = []
    for i in range(len(items)):
        item = items[i]
        if int(item.find('parent').text) == parent:
            children.append({'item': item, 'idx': i + 1})
    return children

def addObject(item, idx, level):
    obj = {}
    name = item.find('name')
    parent = item.find('parent')
    ActualValue = item.find('ActualValue')
    VisibleLevel = item.find('VisibleLevel')
    HighAlertValue = item.find('HighAlertValue')

    if name:
        obj['name'] = name.text
    if parent:
        obj['parent'] = parent.text
    if ActualValue:
        obj['ActualValue'] = ActualValue.text
    if VisibleLevel:
        obj['VisibleLevel'] = VisibleLevel.text
    if HighAlertValue:
        obj['HighAlertValue'] = HighAlertValue.text
        
    children = get_children(idx)
    if (len(children) > 0):
        level += 1
        if (level == 1 or level == 2):
            for c in children:
                obj[c['item'].find("name").text] = addObject(c['item'], int(c['idx']), level)
        elif(level == 3):
            obj['data'] = []
            for c in children:
                obj['data'].append(addObject(c['item'], int(c['idx']), level))
        return obj
    else:
        return obj

result = []
for i in range(len(items)):   
    item = items[i]
    if int(item.find('parent').text) == 0:
        result.append(addObject(item, i + 1, 0))

data_json = json.dumps(result, indent=4)
print(data_json)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta me ajudou muito!